# Unexpected DTD declaration: Composite C1

Tags: c1-cms

Just trying out composite c1 via azure (4.3.5555) and started with a blank page (since it is require valid XHTML, you have to use a namespace http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Writing-XHTML). However the following does not seem to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>test</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It reports "Unexpected DTD declaration" in the event log.

> (Exception message: Unexpected DTD declaration. Line 1, position 59. at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r) at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o) at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options) at Composite.Core.Xml.XhtmlDocument.Parse(String xhtml) at Composite.Core.WebClient.Renderings.Page.PageRenderer.ParsePlaceholderContent(IPagePlaceholderContent placeholderContent) at Composite.Core.PageTemplates.TemplateDefinitionHelper.BindPlaceholders(IPageTemplate template, PageContentToRender pageContentToRender, IDictionary`2 placeholderProperties, FunctionContextContainer functionContextContainer) at Composite.Plugins.PageTemplates.Razor.RazorPageRenderer.RendererPage(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) at Renderers_Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint))

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Master Page layout with this page layout then you need to remove the "<!DOCTYPE html>" declaration from your page layout.